# limit results from database php

Tags: php, html, database

I have this code that will display all of the info on my database. The problem is I want to show only about 10 of the last results. But be able to request more somehow by pressing  button. Thank you for taking interest in my question.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "myDB";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<div id='message'> <br> ". $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"] . "<br> </div>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: you need to use pagination for this

Comment: @Fred-ii- what is pagination.

Comment: @Fred-ii is it possible to do in html.

Comment: You can add pagination like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination http://stackoverflow.com/a/3707457/5807975

Comment: then limit using `$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests LIMIT <START_INDEX>, 10";`

Comment: see the links given by nix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clause for limit selection. [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

if you want to select last 10 data, write query like this.

`SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`

and you should use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for "show more" function.

Comment: Mystika, w3schools.com is not an authenticated resource for reference. You can use php.net or MySQL's official site.

Comment: thanks. how would i make the results shown go back to front. for example "A" is at the top and "J" is at the bottom. i want to make "J" at the top and "A" at the bottom.

Comment: @Pupil agree, I replaced link to MySQL's official document.

Comment: @jack there is ORDER BY clause for that! check out link on my answer :D

Comment: @Mystika it makes it show my first entered content into the server. the desc is correct but i just want that page content that loaded up to be back to front.

Comment: @jack it seems javascript problem. check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6qq91n2b/

Comment: thanks @Mystika but i can't seam to figure out how i can incorporate it into my code.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you could solve this

**Option 1**

> The problem is I want to show only about 10 of the last results

One way to do it is to use the SQL `Limit` specifier

```
$sql="Select * from ORDERS LIMIT 5"
```

this will fetch the 5 items from your database. You can use ordering mechanisms for sorting,etc

> But be able to request more somehow by pressing button.

You can use the `offset` specifier for this.

```
$sql="Select * from ORDERS LIMIT 5 OFFSET 15"
```

This fetches 10 records from the 16th record.You can add to the offset on each button press.

Here is some more information on this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp).

**Option 2**

Pagination.This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434813/simple-pagination-in-javascript) should help.

Comment: would that show the last entered results or going from the top of the database.

Comment: To fetch the last entered results, you could do `ORDER BY` the `id` in `DESC`. If you have a `date` colum, then replace the `id` by data.Any parameter that is taking your entries in a sequential manner.