# Goto 'next' and 'previous' HTML elements within page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a script which uses a global variable to define current shown section, run a function to add or subtract to it, and uses that value to goto next or previous element by displaying a specific section. Basically, multiple pages in one HTML file.

I have updated the page to include your suggestions.

**HTML With In-line JavaScript**

```
<html style="font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:150%;text-indent:2em;text-align:justify;color:000;background:FFF">
    <body style="padding:1% 3% 3% 1%">
        <section id='controls'>
            <h1 id='prev' style="float:left;cursor:context-menu;color:#888" onclick="i('prev')">Prev Chapter</h1>
            <h1 id='next' style="float:left;cursor:hand;color:#0F8" onclick="i('next')">Next Chapter</h1>
        </section>
        <section id='x0' class='x' style="display:block;cursor:context-menu">
            <script>
        var page = 0
        var a = document.getElementById('prev');
        var b = document.getElementById('next');
        var c = document.getElementsByClassName('x');
        function i(action) {
            if (action == 'prev') {
                if (page == 0) {
                    a.style.cursor = 'context-menu';
                    a.style.color = '#FFF';
                } else {
                    a.style.cursor = 'hand';
                    a.style.color = '#08F';
                    page = page - 1
                }
            }
            if (action == 'next') {
                if (page == 0) {
                    b.style.cursor = 'context-menu';
                    b.style.color = '#FFF';
                } else {
                    b.style.cursor = 'hand';
                    b.style.color = '#0F8';
                    page = page + 1
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < c.length; ++i) {c[i].style.display = 'none';}
            document.getElementById('x'+page).style.display = 'block';
        }

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434813/simple-pagination-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks, but, I don't think that's the code I'm looking for.

Comment: `IF (action = 'prev') ` - - this is an assignment, not a comparison, thus it will evaluate as true. For comparisons use the `==` or `===` operators. You have this error several times in your code.

Comment: Try declaring a and b inside of the function, so that they are found when the function is called. It's possible that they don't exist yet when your code runs initially, so they have null instead of the element.

Comment: @iHL  ShamSUP has given  you the answer, the problem is in your `if` statement

Comment: Fixed it, the code works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason javascript dose not care about the action is because you are using the wrong operator. Try using `==` operator in order to make an expression that returns a boolean value.
You can reference operators usage [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

Also consider a conditional statement to not let the page variable go out of the needed bounds for your algorythim (for example -1).
And Also consider loading the script at the end of the `<body>` tag