# Read json file as javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file with all my data inside and I also have a search box

But i would like to add pagination to the results page

I have found this helpful code here [Simple pagination in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434813/simple-pagination-in-javascript/25435422) which shows how it can be done, but the problem is that my data is from a file called data.json

i've tried many things to try and get my data to pull through but none seem to work

```
the below does not work
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    console.log('data',data);
});
```

this is my data

```
{"id":"1","name":"Name 1","channel_id":"37"},{"id":"2","name":"Name 2","channel_id":"41"},{"id":"3","name":"Name 3","channel_id":"37"},
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so, whats the output in the console?

Comment: Hi! More information will make it easier to diagnose the problem. You said your $.getJSON call isn't working, can you be more specific? Does anything log to the console when you try?

Comment: Who upvoted this...?

Comment: I am not sure but I have feeling that most browsers are not actually enabling local file access since you are violating the _Access-Control-Allow-Origin_ rule. It would be better to use the [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Your request would be something like `fetch("data.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your Json is valid. 
When I checked your Json data, it is an array of objects but it is missing []. I corrected your data as below.

```
[{
"id": "1",
"name": "Name 1",
"channel_id": "37"
  }, {
"id": "2",
"name": "Name 2",
"channel_id": "41"
 }, {
"id": "3",
"name": "Name 3",
"channel_id": "37"
 }]
```

Comment: Is it still a json object if it is nested within an array and has the file extension of .json ?

Comment: @Ozan, yes it is even the file extension is .json or anything else. I don't think file extension is important.

Answer (score 0):

The `getJSON` method performs a GET request to your server at the url `data.json`.

You are not providing any details about the location of your file and / or how your server reads and send the JSON data back to the client.

By your question, you are trying to directly read a file called `data.json`, which is not possible. Your server must send the JSON data back to the client by responding to the GET request at the url provided to the `getJSON` method.

Answer (score 0):

the method that you are looking for is `JSON.parse(jsonData)`