# Javascript table's pagination

Tags: javascript, pagination

I'm trying to put pagination function into my table and taking this post "[Simple pagination in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434813/simple-pagination-in-javascript)" for reference.

https://codepen.io/duongvu/pen/eewdPG?editors=1111

It's supposed to input the data from my array into the table's class. However it doesn't work in my case.

It freezes and can not proceed when clicking on `<next>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out @Duong Vu

```
for (var i = 0; i < records_per_page; i++)
 {
    col[i].innerText = content[i + (page-1) * records_per_page].number;
 }
```

Comment: hmmmm.. we need 2 talk.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changePage(page) {
  var btn_next = document.getElementById("btn_next");
  var btn_prev = document.getElementById("btn_prev");
  var col = document.getElementsByClassName("no");
  var colName = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
  var colDetails = document.getElementsByClassName("info");
  var page_span = document.getElementById("page");

  if (page < 1) page = 1;
  if (page > numPages()) page = numPages();

  for (var i = (page - 1) * records_per_page; i < (page * records_per_page); i++) {
    col[i % records_per_page].innerText = content[i] ? content[i].number : '';
    colName[i % records_per_page].innerText = content[i] ? content[i].name : '';
    colDetails[i % records_per_page].innerText = content[i] ? content[i].detail : '';
  }
}
```

You are printing only numbers thats why it was not printing any other result. And as you have only 4 rows, so you need to use `col[i % records_per_page]` to print inside the table data on page changes.

Here is updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/durga598/pen/gXNqGP?editors=1111).