# Pagination via Ajax call in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having one url

url = someurl?limit=5

This will return the 5 elements the format is

```
"count": 290,
"next": "someurl?limit=5&offset=5",
"previous": null,
"status": true,
"result": []
```

What I need to implement a pagination

In initial load it need to be 5 and after scrolling the new datas are append to it

```
     $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            ***********some stuffs for appending data in to html ****
      }
```

In this success data I am getting next url when I was calling data.next

How do I call the same ajax call while data.next to null

Comment: `How do I call the same ajax call while data.next to null` what does this mean ?

Comment: In a ajax call success it returnin data...

In the data.next it having url for the next pagination .... 

For example in initial I am loading 0: 10 datas then the next url for 10:20 datas

SO I need to append those 10:20 elements v

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434813/simple-pagination-in-javascript  .... \

Answer (score 0):

here you need to add in start param that gets incremented as per your limit

/*assuming you are getting your first data on page load increments start from 0 to 5 so you get limit 5,5 in your next records*/

```
<script>
var lmt = 5;
var start = lmt;

fucntion paginate(){
strt = strt + lmt;
url = someurl?limit=lmt&start=strt;
}
</script>
```

using global javascript variables are not secure.