# Button pagination with dots

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am practicing vue and I am trying to build a pagination with Rick Morty Api https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/

Currently looks like:

[image: Table]

I would like to display these buttons in this form `1 2 3 4 5 ... 20` if I click on 20, then it would look like `1 ... 15 16 17 18 19 20`. How can I achieve this? Do I need to use css for this, or pure js and use computed property?

```html
<div class="button_container">
        <button @click="pageChange(i + 1)" v-for="(item, i) in pages" :key="i">
          {{ i + 1 }}
        </button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not that straight forward to do it in a one-liner, the approach I would recommend is to use a `computed`

you could use the function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/67658442/197546

```js
// define method
function paginate(current_page, last_page, onSides = 3) {
  // pages
  let pages = [];
  // Loop through
  for (let i = 1; i <= last_page; i++) {
    // Define offset
    let offset = (i == 1 || last_page) ? onSides + 1 : onSides;
    // If added
    if (i == 1 || (current_page - offset <= i && current_page + offset >= i) ||
        i == current_page || i == last_page) {
        pages.push(i);
    } else if (i == current_page - (offset + 1) || i == current_page + (offset + 1)) {
        pages.push('...');
    }
  }
  return pages;
}

// then in component...
data:{
  return{
    pages:[...],
    currentPage: 0,
  }
},
//...
computed: {
  pageNums = () {
    return paginate(this.currentPage, this.pages.length, 4)
  }
}
```

then, because the `...` should not have an event listener, you can use `<template>` and `v-if` to use different element

```html
<div class="button_container">
  <template v-for="(pageNum, i) in pages" :key="i">
    <button v-if="Number.isInteger(pageNum)" @click="currentPage = i">
      {{ pageNum }}
    </button>
    <span v-else>
      {{ pageNum }}
    </span>
  </template >
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm it doesn't return any dots, just from 1 to 34 buttons

Comment: did you mean `v-for pageNum in pageNums` and not `in pages`?

Comment: meant to do `<template v-for="(pageNum, i) in pages" :key="i">`

Comment: need the `i` still for the key