# How to change the active in pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pagination, anchor

I have a pagination and I want the active class to be in color red. I have this code:

script.js:

```js
$(".pagination").append("<li class='page-item' id='previous-page'><a class='page-link' href='javascript:void(0)' aria-label=Previous><span aria-hidden=true>&raquo;</span></a></li>");
    $(".pagination").append("<li class='current-page active'><a class='page-link' href='javascript:void(0)'>" + 1 + "</a></li>");
    for (var i = 2; i <= totalPages; i++) {
      $(".pagination").append("<li class='current-page'><a class='page-link' href='javascript:void(0)'>" + i + "</a></li>"); // Insert page number into pagination tabs
    }
    $(".pagination").append("<li class='page-item' id='next-page'><a class='page-link' href='javascript:void(0)' aria-label=Next><span aria-hidden=true>&raquo;</span></a></li>");
    
    $(".pagination li.current-page").on("click", function() {
      //checks if the user is at the current page
      if($(this).hasClass("active")){
        return false;
      }else{
        //removes active class and adds it from what the user is clicking
        var currentPage = $(this).index();
        $(".pagination li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#page .content").hide();
}
```

style.css:

```css
.pagination a:active{
  background-color: red;
  color:red;
}
```

I have this code but when I clicked on a `<a>` tag it ony colors it red when clicked but when you release the mouse it turns blue again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active), but select the element by class with `.active`.

```css
.pagination li.active > a {
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but it is still in color blue

Comment: @Dhenhice I cannot reproduce it. It works fine given the code in the question (although the HTML is assumed): https://jsfiddle.net/f4zj5vnu/

Comment: @Dhenhice You could try `.pagination li.active > a` though.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following css.
Working Example https://codepen.io/sethuramancbe/pen/NWOgBNE

```
.pagination .active a{
background-color: red;
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it out. Maybe This gonna help.

```js
const listEl = document.querySelector(".page-index");
const prevBnt = document.querySelector(".prev");
const nextBnt = document.querySelector(".next");

let currentActive = 1;

nextBnt.addEventListener("click", e => {
  currentActive++;

  if (currentActive > Array.from(listEl.children).length) {
    currentActive = Array.from(listEl.children).length;
  }
  updateActive();
});

prevBnt.addEventListener("click", e => {
  currentActive--;

  if (currentActive < 1) {
    currentActive = 1;
  }
  updateActive();
});

function updateActive() {
  Array.from(listEl.children)
    .forEach((item, idx) => {
      if (currentActive > idx) {
        removeActive();
        item.classList.add("active");
      }

    });
}

function removeActive() {
  Array.from(listEl.children)
    .forEach(item => {
      item.classList.remove("active");
    });
}
```

```css
.wraper {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px 20px;
}

ul {}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

nav ul li {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li.active {
  background-color: red;
}

nav button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="wraper">
    <nav>
      <button type="button" class="prev">&larr;</button>
      <ul class="page-index">
        <li class="active">0</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" class="next">&rarr;</button>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here you will find full working pagination example  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298189/implement-pagination-in-javascript-with-limit-and-offset/76798169#76798169